# Convert view filter into controller filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to optimize performance by moving code from view to controller.

---

I would like to move this code in my **view**:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {passed:false} | filter: data.searchQuery | filter: deepSearch() | orderBy: 'begin_datetime'"
```

to something like this in my **controller**:

```
  $scope.filteredItems = [];

  var applyFilters = function() {
    var items = [];
    items = $filter({passed:false})($scope.items);
    items = $filter($scope.data.searchQuery)(items);
    items = $filter($scope.deepSearch())(items);
    $scope.filteredItems = items;
  }
```

in order to get this in my **view**:

```
ng-repeat="item in filteredItems | orderBy: 'begin_datetime'"
```

---

However, I'm getting stuck with

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: [object Object]FilterProvider <- [object Object]Filter

Is there an easy way of doing this?

---

### Answer

Thanks to @SoluableNonagon answer, the correct syntax is:

```
  $scope.filteredItems = [];

  var applyFilters = function() {
    var items = [];
    items = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {passed:false});
    items = $filter('filter')(items, $scope.data.searchQuery);
    items = $filter('filter')(items, $scope.deepSearch());
    $scope.filteredItems = items;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to inject $filter into your controller

```
app.controller('myController', function($filter){
```

Also,

I believe filtering programatically requires a filter name, like so:

$scope.b = $filter('myFilter')($scope.items);

http://jsfiddle.net/MAxrh/

**Update:**

If you want to filter programatically, and it's just a regular search, then the filter name will be just 'filter'

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator) // comparator is optional
```

the HTML equivalent is:

```
{{ array | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/dzPegkZaHOlHWfpVKGEV?p=preview

Comment: I did:   .controller(
  'SearchCtrl',
  [
    '$scope',
    '$cordovaGeolocation',
    'Cache',
    'localize',
    'DSCacheFactory',
    'logger',
    '$cordovaNetwork',
    '$ionicSideMenuDelegate',
    '$filter',

    function ($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, Cache, localize, DSCacheFactory, logger, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $filter) {

Comment: how about filter naming? when filtering programatically, you may need to specify a filter name.

Comment: I see. But how would I write "{passed:false}" using a filter name? Do I need to create my own filters?

Comment: According to this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider, it seems like I'm supposed to register a filter but I'm not sure how and where to do it.